# When I upload pdf document on Server. it,s save pdf but pdf size is 0 byte

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.2, c#-7.3

i have to upload pdf on server on his particular folder. but tried upload code as below. after pdf save and load on my site it's show "Failed to load PDF document."

i check uploaded pdf on server it,s size always 0 byte. i also tried to off compression then upload but not work. as the same code perfect work for images and video.

```
public async Task<string> UploadPDF(IFormFile formFile)
{
    string newFileName = 
            UploadExtensions.GetUniqueFileName(formFile.FileName);
            string fileDirectoryPath;

            fileDirectoryPath = 
            Path.Combine(_configuration["UploadPath"], "uploads/pdf");

            string savePath = Path.Combine(fileDirectoryPath, 
               newFileName);

            await formFile.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(savePath, 
              FileMode.Create));

            return newFileName;
}
```

upload pdf and save on server folder where i create and load in html page

Answer (score 0):

You're not flushing the `FileStream`. You need to do it like:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    await formFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```